# Растягивание изображения

Tags: android

Как сделать растягивание изображения как в Viber'e? Когда зажимаешь картинку контакта и тянешь вниз и она расширяется, а отпустишь палец размер картинки станет нормальным.

Comment: через onTouchListener. Сомневаюсь, что есть готовые решения

Comment: это не растягивание картинки. тут Paralax header, просто немного подифицированный. Гуглить по этому словосочетанию

Answer (score 13):

Выдался мне свободный денек и решил реализовать я предложенную задачу.  Сразу небольшой демонстрационный проект на [GitHub](https://github.com/pavlofff/StretchView), картинка (прошу прощения за розовую херню, такая программа захвата попалась) и ниже немного пояснений.
[image: скриншот]

Реализовать подобный эффект можно несколькими способами, я решил выбрать самый простой - расширение `FrameLayout`, который, как известно позволяет наложить элементы друг на друга, смещение двух элементов и управление движением через `onTouchEvent()`, плюс еще замечательная анимация возврата при отпускании.
Собственно сам класс расширяющий `FrameLayout`:

```
// имя пакета, потребуется в разметке, у вас будет какое-то свое
package com.example.stretchview;  

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class StretchLayout extends FrameLayout {
  final float DEFAULT_RATIO = 0.5F;
  float mTouchY;
  float mTranslateY;
  float mMargin;
  float mRatio;
  View mStretchView;
  View mFrontView ;

 public StretchLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
 }

 public StretchLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
 }

 public StretchLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
 }

 private void init() {
  mRatio = DEFAULT_RATIO;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mTouchY = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mTranslateY = event.getY() - mTouchY;
            if (mTranslateY >= mMargin) mTranslateY = mMargin;
            if (mTranslateY <0) mTranslateY = 0;
            mFrontView.setTranslationY(mTranslateY);
            mStretchView.setTranslationY(mTranslateY/2);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mTranslateY = 0;
            mFrontView.animate().translationY(mTranslateY).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            mStretchView.animate().translationY(mTranslateY).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            break;
    }
 return true;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    mStretchView = getChildAt(0);
    mFrontView = getChildAt(1);
    mMargin = mStretchView.getMeasuredHeight()*mRatio;
    mFrontView.setTop((int)(mMargin));
    mStretchView.setTop((int) (-mMargin/2));
 }

 protected void setRatio (float ratio){
    mRatio = ratio;
 }
}
```

Теперь - как этим пользоваться.

Создаем разметку (`activity_main.xml`), которая обязательно должна включать два элемента, названные мной `stretch_view`- тот, что частично скрывается и `front_view` - который его закрывает - вы можете использовать свои идентификаторы. Второй элемент у меня `LinearLayout`, который содержит пару кнопок для примера.

Параметр `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` указывает,чтобы изображение занимало только необходимое ему по размерам место.

Так же прошу обратить внимание на то, как указан наш кастомный лэйаут - с полным именем, включающим название пакета этого лэйаута.

```
 <com.example.stretchview.StretchLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/stretch_view"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/front_view"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
  </LinearLayout>

 </com.example.stretchview.StretchLayout>
```

Активити, в которой все это вызывается не блещет оригинальностью:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Если дефолтный коэффициент перекрытия (половина высоты изображения) не устраивает - его можно изменить методом `setRatio(float ratio)`, `ratio` может принимать значения от 0 до 1 ( картинку полностью не видно - картинка полностью раскрыта)

Конечно здесь есть еще,что улучшить, к примеру парсинг этого `ratio` из xml-аттрибутов разметки, дополнительные проверки от падения и тп.
Может где то я совершил по незнанию что то страшное, прошу строго не судить, а ткнуть носом ..  все это на самом деле замечательно работает.

Минимальный API - 14, для 2.* андроид много костылей надо

Comment: Даёшь на гитхаб