# Выбор Layout для компоновки виджетов на экране

Tags: android, android-layout

Пытаюсь сделать приложение, которое будет показывать наверху в заголовке фото (для красоты), потом на нижней границе заголовка FloatingActionButton (для показа списка всех BLE beacon, найденных рядом) и внизу две строчки текста (имя и MAC-адрес выбранного BLE beacon) и кнопку "Удалить".

Bluetooth-код работает хорошо, а вот с layout не могу разобраться, пожалуйста, помогите.

Я отметил красными стрелками, куда собственно должны встать элементы:

[image: app screenshot]

Вот мой activity_main.xml, почему `layout_gravity="bottom"` не опускает 2 строчки текста и кнопку вниз?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unknown"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/header"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:onClick="selectDevice"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

И styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
</resources>
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**

Перешел на RelativeLayout, как предложено [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts), но не понимаю, как опустить кнопку "Delete" вниз - чтобы лучше использовать место на экране:

[image: screenshot]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Unknown"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/header"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:onClick="selectDevice"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: думаю вместо `FrameLayout` нужно использовать `LinearLayout` или `RelativeLayout`, так как `FrameLayout` создает новый слой

Comment: и все элементы в нем размещаются от верхнего левого угла. У него очень ограниченные возможности позиционирования (через gravity), которые не позволят вам разместить элементы как вы хотите

Comment: Спасибо (+1) перешел на `RelativeLayout` (см. update), но как опустить текст и кнопку ниже?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPD2**

В библиотеке поддержки добавилось несколько новых компоновочных контейнеров:

`PercentRelativeLayout` и `PercentFrameLayout` (библиотека *android.support:percent*) - компоновщики имеют все те же атрибуты, что и их "родители", кроме того появилась возможность указывать отступы, расстояния и размеры для вложенных в контейнер виджетов  в процентах от размеров самого контейнера. [Пример](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/percent-part-1/)

`FlexboxLayout` (библиотека *com.google.android:flexbox*) - по свойствам схож с `LinearLayout`,виджеты располагаются друг за другом, однако имеет существенное отличие - когда  виджеты доходят до границы контейнера, они переносятся "на следующую строку", а не теряются за его границей (аналогичен `FlowLayout` на десктопе). Так же имеет несколько атрибутов позиционирования и взаиморасположения виджетов между собой и в контейнере. [Пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/300908/)

`ConstraintLayout` - (библиотека поддержки *android.support.constraint:constraint-layout*) -  контейнер похож на `RelativeLayout`, поддерживается только начиная с Android Studio 2.2, где для его использования переписали визуальный редактор.
Принцип позиционирования основан на "резиновой" верстке, где вы можете указать расстояния между виджетами, границы для них и взаимное расположение, при этом относительные размеры в верстке будут сохранятся при поворотах или разных размерах и плотностях экрана

Описать это очень сложно, поэтому скриншот должен внести ясность. В виду повышенной сложности Google даже сделала официальный анимированный [туториал по использованию](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

Существует отдельная группа контейнеров, не так давно добавленная гугл в виде библиотек поддержки, которые относятся не столько к компоновщикам элементов на экране, сколько к организации их взаимодействия между собой.

Например, `CoordinatorLayout` используется для анимированного взаимодействия элементов. Всякие выдвигающиеся или там всплывающие штуки.
По сути это `FrameLayout` с возможностями связывания элементов в динамике.
Он позволяет связывать двигающиеся элементы внутри себя так, что они не теряют связи при движении и могут взаимодействовать. Использовать можно в любых типах анимации, например всплывающий `SnackBar` - при его появлении остальные элементы смещаются, чтобы он не перекрывал их или выдвигающаяся при скроллинге вниз картинка.

Так как это модифицированный `FrameLayout`, то для группировки элементов внутри него, если их несколько, необходимо использовать другие контейнеры, чтобы разместить элементы так, как требуется.

В общем то аналогичного поведения можно добиться и при использовании основных контейнеров, но ранее для этого приходилось их определенным образом модифицировать, как, например, [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422750/177345) - теперь гугл сделала собственный механизм, включенный в API Android.

**Основной ответ**

`FrameLayout` не подходит для выбранной вами компоновки, так как этот контейнер (по умолчанию) размещает все вложенные в него элементы в верхний левый край, с наложением одних на другие.
Это самый простой из контейнеров и позиционирование внутри него ограничено свойством `gravity`, то есть кроме верхнего левого края, элементы можно разместить по центру или привязать к другим краям (правый, верх, низ), также возможны отступы от краев - `padding` и\или  `margin` - на этом возможности компоновки в данном контейнере заканчиваются.

Как видите этого недостаточно для размещения элементов последовательно - один за другим, либо  еще какого-то относительного связывания вложенных элементов между собой внутри данного контейнера.

Для более сложных компоновок используются контейнеры:

`LinearLayout`- вложенные элементы идут друг за другом по вертикали или горизонтали.

`TableLayout` - вложенные элементы размещаются в структуру таблицы. По сути это горизонтальные `LinearLayout` вложенные в вертикальный `LinearLayout` в более удобном представлении. Поскольку ячейки таблицы могут иметь разный размер и в каждой строке может быть разное количество ячеек, то с его помощью можно скомпоновать довольно сложные разметки,составные элементы которой можно разбить на ячейки ( а это почти все в реальности)

`GridLayout` - технически повторяет `TableLayout`, но более функциональный и имеет дополнительные возможности в части позиционирования элементов ( можно указать номер конкретной ячейки, где разместить элемент), также позволяет размещать несколько элементов в одной ячейке и некоторые другие возможности.

`RelativeLayout` - вложенные элементы связываются друг с другом линками между собой и\или границами контейнера - это самый сложный (и самый ресурсоемкий) компоновщик, позволяет практически произвольно размещать элементы внутри себя, в том числе и с наложением один на другой, без центровки по осям и прочие чудеса.

Существует еще несколько менее популярных контейнеров на которых я останавливаться не буду.

Выбирать контейнер надо из соображений достаточной функциональности. Выше они расположены в порядке приоритета, то есть если для компоновки достаточно `LinearLayout`, то использовать `RelativeLayout` будет излишним расточительством ресурсов устройства, так как это намного более ресурсоемкий контейнер.

Отдельно нужно заметить по поводу вложения одного контейнера в другой - если есть возможность скомпоновать виджеты в один контейнер, то это предпочтительнее, чем использовать вложенные контейнеры, то есть `RelativeLayout` будет предпочтительнее трех вложенных `LinearLayout`, чем линейней получается структура компоновки, тем лучше для производительности, как правило.

Comment: Спасибо! А на каком месте в вашем списке CoordinatorLayout и в чем его смысл? Его используют в основном с ListView и RecycleView?

Comment: добавил в ответ

Comment: Хороший ответ! Раньше все старался делать с помощью `LinearLayout` так как их можно вкладывать друг в друга и делать почти любые модификации, но теперь хочу обратить внимание на `TableLayout`... Я так понял я него такие же возможности только менее ресурсоемкий...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Выбирать компоновщик разметки следует из решаемых задач, а не личных симпатий. В каких-то ситуациях предпочтителен один, в других - другой. `TableLayout` по своей сути `LinearLayout` с вложенными `LinearLayout`, только имеет некоторые встроенные дополнительные возможности по относительному форматированию колонок для упрощения разметки.

Comment: @pavlofff я это и имел в виду...

Comment: Круто, спасибо за объяснения. Теперь ждём различных туториалов по использованию новых фич :)

Answer (score 1):

К кнопке delete добавь свойство `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`