# Наложить TextView на ImageView - XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-sdk, android-layout

Есть разметка, которая состоит так:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/clothes"
        android:src="@drawable/clothes"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ABCD"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как наложить текст на картинку?
А то мои попытки игры с Padding и margin неудачны.

Comment: [немного информации](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439923/177345) по выбору типа контейнера для компоновки виджетов на экране.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто замените `LinearLayout` на `FrameLayout`. Используемый вами всегда все свои элементы располагает по очереди (вертикально/горизонтально). Второй же (`FrameLayout`) располагает элементы по z оси. И так у вас текстовое поле наложится на картинку.

Comment: вроде как RelativeLayout даст тот же эффект. Или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: @researcher, да, но он "тяжелее" и если не требуется пользоваться его возможностями относительного позиционирования, то лучше взять  "легковесный" `FrameLayout`. Я это где-то когда-то вычитал)

Comment: Интересно в чем "вес" измерялся) Если наткнетесь на то, где вычитали - киньте ссылкой в меня)

Comment: @researcher, ох, ссылку врядли я найду) А "вес", уверен, зависит от количества операций по вычислению конечных координат/размеров дочерних элементов. В `RelativeLayout` их должно быть больше, засим он должен есть больше ресурсов при прочих равных.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать)