# Новый стандартный эмулятор в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

На I/O Extended 16 была презентована новая версия Android Studio, в которой обновился стандартный эмулятор. Как утверждают разработчики, новый эмулятор стал в 16 раз быстрее собирать проекты, требует в несколько раз меньшее количество ресурсов и т.д.

Кто-нибудь уже разбирался и сравнивал НОВЫЙ стандартный эмулятор и Genymotion? Что лучше, что быстрее, почему?

Comment: Новый эмулятор появился с версии 2.0 и к времени сборки он отношения не имеет. Скорректируйте и уточните свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Новый эмулятор доступен уже давно, еще вместе с Android Studio 2.0.
Да, он быстрее старого намного. На хорошем железе быстрее некоторых средних телефонов.
В Android Studio 2.2, представленной на I/O 2016 ускорена сборка проектов и загрузка APK на устройсто/эмулятор.
В новом эмуляторе много полезных фич, динамический размер, скриншоты одним кликом, drag-n-drop и т.п.
Просто попробуйте, все это уже есть вместе с последней стабильной Android Studio 2.1.1.

Comment: Вопрос-то про сравнение с Genymotion.

Comment: @D-side вопрос вообще не понятен, т.к. эмулятор никакого отношения к сборке проекта не имеет.

Comment: @temq Такое лучше в комментариях к **вопросу** замечать.

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion однозначно лучше и быстрее. В новом эмуляторе в студии бережно сохранили все старые баги. Вот [тут](http://pr0andr0id.blogspot.ru/2016/04/android-studio-151-20.html) в конце статьи можете почитать.

Answer (score -1):

Я понимаю, что это не ответ на вопрос, но хотелось бы обратить внимание на нововведения в Android Studio 2.2 , раз уж речь зашла о последнем Google I/O и этой IDE

В представленой на Google I/O Android Studio 2.2 [следующие нововведения](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html):

1. Новый визуальный редактор с существенными улучшениями под новый контейнер ConstraintLayout (немного описал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439923/177345))
2. Визуальный редактор для файлов разметки Menu и Preferences
3. Layout Inspector для теста нагруженности разметки прямо в Android Studio
4. Улучшенный Lint и инспекции
5. Переработанный браузер сэмплов, теперь можно вставлять сэмплы прямо в свой код
6. Улучшена поддержка С++
7. Плагин Firebase
8. Компилятор Jack с поддержкой Java 8
9. IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 в базе, со всеми ее [основными фишками](https://habrahabr.ru/company/JetBrains/blog/280019/).
10. APK Analyzer для решения проблем с скомпилированным приложением: размер, проблема 64K и тп

    А новый эмулятор представлен еще в версии AS2.0

Comment: Я тоже "понимаю, что это не ответ на вопрос", так зачем же его здесь размещать? Создайте сами новый вопрос типа "Какие есть нововведения в Android Studio 2.2 ?" и вот туда и поместите свой ответ ;-)

Comment: @KromStern  вопрос такой: что с эмулятором на презентации AS Google I/O 16, а ответ такой, что с эмулятором ничего, а вот с другими функциями есть изменения, поэтому и здесь пригодится.