# Как выровнять тексты и кнопку в RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, xml

Добрый день!
Есть RelativeLayout с TextView и ImageView (срелочка).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу, чтобы стрелочка всегда была справа и centerVertical="true", и текст не налезал на нее.

Текущий код

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one_news_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/text_for_delete"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/one_news_second_icon"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/one_news_second_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_hardware_keyboard_arrow_right"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Но возникают проблемы, если информации, допустим, меньше, чем 3 строки. Все сползает на левую сторону.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что это из-за атрибута android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/one_news_second_icon"
но если его убрать, текст начинает залезать на стрелку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как достичь золотой середины?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для такой компоновки `RelativeLayout` не нужен и избыточен Используйте `LinearLayout` с указанием веса для виджета `TextView`,чтобы он занимал все свободное место, оставляя только картинку с левого края

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/one_news_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/text_for_delete"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/one_news_second_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_hardware_keyboard_arrow_right"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Почему не `RelativeLayout`:

Это во много более ресурсоемкий контейнер нагружающий систему, при том, что возможности его здесь никак не используются, а наоборот создают проблемы.
Вам нужно разместить два виджета друг за другом последовательно, такую задачу решает `LinearLayout`, он специально для этого создан и гарантирует, что один виджет не будет перекрывать другой ни при каких условиях - всегда сохранится их ряд.
`RelativeLayout` основан не на следовании виджетов друг за другом, а на их взаимных связях, при этом он никак не учитывает границы соседних виджетов и легко позволяет накладывать виджеты друг на друга, это очень полезно, но не в вашем случае здесь. В вашей задаче придется принимать дополнительные меры, чтобы виджеты не перекрывались и сохраняли определенное соотношение. Достичь такого этим компоновщиком может и можно, но мне даже не хочется думать - как, потому что это бессмысленная и не очевидно решаемая задача, данный контейнер не предполагает инструментов для ее решения, останется что то костылить, перебирать, подбирать и расстраиваться от неудачного результата.

Comment: то есть в RelativeLayout так сделать нельзя?

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid может и можно как то, но точно не нужно. `RelativeLayout` гораздо более "тяжелый" контейнер, для данной компоновки его использовать просто бессмысленно - он для совсем другой компоновки,тем более когда можно достичь того же результата более правильным и простым образом. Зачем вам именно `RelativeLayout` здесь сдался? - задачи нужно решать с позиции оптимизации, разумной достаточности и банальной логики, а не из личных "симпатий".

Comment: я с вами полностью согласна про результат и путь к нему, просто мне всегда казалось, что Layout'ы между собой достаточно взаимозаменяемы при определенном уровне навыков. То есть один и тот же макет можно сделать по-разному. Спросила, потому что хочу и понимать, как можно, а как нет.
А если про личные симпатии, мне нравится, как вы отвечаете. Я маньячу за вашими ответами)) очень логично и понятно объясняете.

Comment: У вас здесь требуется разместить два виджета друг за другом - это задача именно `LinearLayout`, он здесь самый оптимальный вариант и создан именно для такой компоновки. Макет можно скомпоновать по разному, да, но оптимально обычно только одним способом. Если вы прогоните свою разметку через тестер нагруженности разметки *HierarchyViewer* (входит в SDK Tools, а с версии AS2.2 интегрирован прямо в IDE), то увидите, что оптимизация разметки не пустой звук. Я [вот здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439923/177345) писал немного по контейнерам (там читать с конца надо, после апдейтов)

Comment: Спасибо! 
Я про HierarchyViewer даже не знала ._.

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid так [скорее узнайте](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/hierachyviewer.php) и используйте

Comment: ну вообще лучше использовать relative, вместо leinar с весами

Comment: @andreich Определенно нет, но вы можете предложить свой вариант компоновки на основе `RelativeLayout`, решающий задачу в вопросе.

Comment: @pavlofff, я усиленно пошла изучать HierarchyViewer, но у меня не загружается сама иерархия. http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=c4caedd072e52162f6f281e3a384b7e5
делала всё, как указано здесь 
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer-walkthru.html
дохожу до 9 пункта, дальше у меня не идет. подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина?
(не знаю, надо ли это уже переносить всё в другую тему, если что извините).

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid Если вас это утешит, то в последнее время я наблюдаю то же самое, разбираться мне пока лень, думаю в Google что то там наулучшали как всегда и теперь ничего не работает. Я пока собираюсь ждать фикса, а потом посмотрим

Comment: @pavlofff, да, вполне ответ :) вы если заметите, что то-то измениться, дайте знать)

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid Ну вот с некоторых пор вверены какие то ограничения в Hierarchy Viewer, что он не работает напрямую с залоченными устройствами у которых API < 17 (Android 4.0 и ниже). А на устройствах с API > 16 требуется прописать переменную окружения. Инструкция по настройке [здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer-setup.html)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте у textView выставить `android:gravity="center|left"`

Comment: У меня тогда ImageView совсем исчезает
http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=364f9d43c32efa1a456ce4f189c6a1f1

Comment: щас обновлю ответ, неправильно написал..

Comment: все равно сползает направо