# android studio мешает располагать объекты

Tags: java, android

хочу расположить кнопочки по-своему, а студио мне "помогает", и каждый элемент привязывает ко всему, что видит, из-за чего у меня всё вместе начинает перемещаться. я уже понял из-за чего: дописываются привязки в виде XML как android:layout. можно выключить автоматическую привязку, или запретить для данного объекта? очень надоедает редактировать XML

Comment: Измените тип layout'а на более подходящий для Ваших задач. К примеру, LinearLayout

Comment: @VAndrJ, можно подробнее? я с этой фигнёй работаю впервые.

Comment: нет, не пойдёт. мне надо сделать калькулятор

Comment: @EgorRandomize, вы в визуальном редакторе разметку делаете? Если да - то не делайте в нём и проблем не будет. Графический редактор ужасен и использовать его нельзя

Comment: в нём самом. я полностью согласен с тобой. нужно писать кодом тогда в activity_main.xml?

Comment: Как по мне, для калькулятора LinearLayout идеально подойдет

Comment: @VAndrJ На самом деле идеально подойдет `TableLayout` или `GridView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну *во-первых*, как Вам уже подсказали прекратите пользоваться графическим редактором, но как правило не к чему хорошему не приводит, потому как перетаскивая элементы приложения туда сюда, Вы нагромождаете себя дополнительными строками кода, который потом Вам и "помогает".

*Во-вторых*, смело переходите в Ваш файл - ориентировочно activity_main.xml и ознакамливайтесь со следующими понятиями:
[RelativeLayout](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/relativelayout.php), [LinearLayout](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/linearlayout.php), [TableLayout](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/tablelayout.php), [GridLayout](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/gridlayout.php). Именно благодаря им, Вы сможете сделать подходящий макет.

Ну и конечно же не забудьте пролистать команды для xml, которые как Вы говорите "помогает", они на самом деле помогают, если их использовать по назначению.

Comment: вот это я понимаю, ответ развёрнутый, полезный и без бамбалейло. смело можно считать лучшим

Answer (score 1):

В андроид достаточно [много компоновочных контейнеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439923/177345) и ваша задача, как разработчика, подобрать наиболее подходящий по ваши задачи, а не использовать предложенный по умолчанию (В частности для верстки кнопок калькулятора наиболее подходят табличные контейнеры: `GridLayout`, `TableLayout`).

Автоматическая привязка вложенных в контейнер виджетов на визуальном макете действует только для двух типов контейнеров - `RelativeLayout` и `ConstraintLayout`, при этом по дефолту Android Studio предлагает именно `RelativeLayout`.

Если при использовании `ConstrainLayout` автоматическое связывание виджетов в окне Design  можно отключить, [нажав на значок магнитика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/532100/177345) (чтобы он стал зачеркнутым), то для `RelativeLayout` связывание отключить нельзя и такой макет приходится корректировать вручную, через свойства контейнера (properties) справа от визуального отображения (удаляя в атрибутах у виджетов ссылки на другие виджеты для ненужных связей), либо писать изначально xml-код, вместо визуального редактора.

Какие атрибуты отвечают за связывание в `RelativeLayout` можно посмотреть в [этой таблице](http://www.fandroid.info/relative-layout-osobennosti-maketov-ekranov-android-prilozhenij/)