# Абсолютное позиционирование в Android

Tags: android

Скажите пожалуйста, как в Android можно задать абсолютное позиционирование элементу? Например, в web разметке можно указать свойства position:absolute и z-index, но в студии подобного я пока не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В API Android есть [`AbsoluteLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html), объявленный устаревшим уже в API 3, так как в мобильной разработке нет места абсолютным координатам. Существует огромное количество размеров и плотностей экранов, а абсолютное позиционирование позволяет сверстать экран только для одного из них (при других параметрах экрана разметка "поедет") - это крайне не эффективно.

Вам нужно освоить [приемы "резиновой"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345) (адаптивной) верстки, когда одна разметка подходит под многие размеры экранов, подстраиваясь под них. Такую верстку позволяют организовать все [прочие контейнеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439923/177345) API Android, так что есть из чего выбрать. Однако, если в силу каких то неведомых причин вам нужно именно абсолютное позиционирование, вы можете использовать давно позабытый контейнер `AbsoluteLayout` на свой страх и риск, учитывая его статус.

Comment: Ну или можете кинуть любой другой современный и задавать координаты из кода, оперируя размером экрана и margin - ами. Это мне кажется более правильный подход.