# Резиновый дизайн для Android

Tags: android, javafx, дизайн, design

Приветствую. Можно как-нибудь под Android писать резиновый интерфейс (Как в JavaFX с использованием FXML и AnchorPlane)? Пилить дизайн по каждый экран - надоело, если честно.

Comment: Не хочется вас расстраивать, но под Android и используется [только "резиновый" интерфейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663660/177345), никто не пишет дизайн под каждый экран в здравом уме (учитывая фрагментацию android -устройств, их, наверное, сотни )

Comment: @pavlofff Да, я слышал про ConstraintLayout. Просто когда я делал приложения, этого ещё не было и приходилось 6 страниц верстать по каждый ДПИ.

Comment: `ConstrainLayout` здесь совершенно не причем, любой контейнер в Android имеет все возможности для "резиновой" верстки. В комментарии выше есть ссылка на [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345), почитайте, что там написано очень внимательно - лучше вам уже вряд ли объяснишь. Если вы все равно не понимаете принципов верстки под несколько экранов, то  попробуйте приложить к вопросу конкретную верстку, которую вы не можете адаптировать под несколько экранов или уточните, что именно у вас вызывает затруднения.