# Создание gif-анимации демонстрирующей работу приложения

Tags: android, android-studio, видео, gif

**Дано:**

Приложение, выложенное на `github`.

**Задача:**

В `README` поместить `gif`-анимацию работы приложения.

**Возможное решение:**

В `AndroidStudio` видел кнопку "сделать видео работы приложения" (там же где скриншоты делаются). Беглое гугленье по запросу

> [making gifs from video](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=making%20gifs%20from%20video)

выдаёт следующий сайт: [типа он-лайн преобразование видео в gif](http://makeagif.com/video-to-gif). И ни одной ссылки на `SO`!

**Вопрос:**

Является ли вышеописанный способ единственным решением задачи? И если нет, то существуют ли какие-то специализированные инструменты для создания `gif`-анимации работы приложения?

Comment: Если что, я в чате спрашивал - сказали, что вопрос относится к написанию документации и засим уместен на ru-SO. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24210883#24210883

Comment: Вот нашёл ещё статейку на тему: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/creating-gif-images-from-your-android-device/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инструментов, создающих сразу же gif-анимацию, происходящего на устройстве, пожалуй, нет.

Проблема решается в два "захода":

1. Записывается видео.
2. Записанное видео конвертируется в GIF

По первому пункту есть три основных способа получить желаемое:

1. [Инструмент Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html#screenCap) , делающий видео, происходящего на устройстве.
   Ограничения: API>=19 и длительность не более 3 минут.
2. [Команда adb записывающая видео](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/shell.html#screenrecord) происходящего на экране на устройство:
   `adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/screen_record.mp4`/ Остановить запись - <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>
   Ограничения: API >=19 и длительность не более 3 минут.
3. [Приложения для записи видео](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=screen%20record&c=apps), которые устанавливаются на устройство.
   Таких множество, но найти более-менее годную и бесплатную мне пока не удалось ([вот что получается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422750/177345) c *Recordable FREE*)
   Так же такой программе обычно требуются права root и большинство из них ограничено все тем же API>=19.
   Однако, некоторые из них (как *[Recordable](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.org.invisibility.recordablefree)*) могут сделать видео и на API<19 или с длительностью более 3 минут, что делает их единственным решением в некоторых случаях.

По второму пункту есть множество [онлайн сервисов](http://yandex.ru/search/?text=convert%20video%20gif%20online), которые сделают GIF из видео файла, так же как и программ, устанавливающихся на компьютер. Например [Free Video to GIF Converter](http://www.video-gif-converter.com/)

PS: Бонус - [ссылка на en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382212/capture-video-of-androids-screen) по вопросу