# Библиотека с Изменением ScrollView

Tags: java, android, design

Есть разметка следующего вида:

70 процентов экрана - Изображение
30 - ScrolView с текстом и кнопкой "Оценить"

Так как 30% - слишком мало, чтобы увидеть текст и удобно прочитать, ищу библиотеку (или штатные средства Android), при помощи которой можно "наехать" ScrollView на изображение. То есть пользователь может растянуть содержимое ScrollView если потянет за верхний край.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Можете [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422750/177345) посмотреть в качестве направления, если хочется самому реализовать, а так вообще сейчас есть `CoordinatorLayout` для таких случаев специально.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот такую разметку. У гугла уже есть готовые инструменты для этого.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Так же не забудьте добавить зависимость в градл, если еще нет
`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'`

Answer (score 1):

Тут ничего хитрого нет.
Есть общий корневой контейнер - `RelativeLayout`. В нем еще 2 вью, `ImageView` и контейнер `ScrollView`. По сколько `ScrollView` установлен последним, он будет "накладываться" на `ImageView`. Далее нужен контейнер для текста и кнопки в любом случае - это будет `LinearLayout`. Ну и что бы наш текст с кнопкой был ПОД картинкой, ставим паддинг для их рут контейнера, у меня в примере он равен высоте картинки + отступ `428dp`. Ну и что бы наше добро скролилось вверх, нужно установить паддинг снизу. Удачи!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.chaynik.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="372dp"
            android:paddingTop="428dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="128dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Chaynik The Best"
                    android:textSize="36sp" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Подтверждаю!" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```